# Taking specific part of line

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

Hi I've got a log file containing trace routes and pings.
Ive seperated these by using

```
if (scanner.nextLine ().startsWith ("64 bytes"){}
```

so I can work with just the pings for now.

All I'm interested in from the ping is time=XX

example data line =

```
64 bytes from ziva.zarnet.ac.zw (209.88.89.132): icmp_seq=119 ttl=46 time=199 ms
```

I have been reading other peoples similar questions and I'm not sure how to apply to mine.

I literally need just the numbers as I will be putting them into a csv file so I can make a graph of the data.

edit: Using robins solution I'm now having my pings being spurted out on screen, except it's doing every other and missing the first.

```
 while (scanner.hasNextLine ()) {
   //take only pings.
   if (scanner.nextLine ().startsWith ("64 bytes")){
       String line = scanner.nextLine ();       
       String pingAsString = line.substring (line.lastIndexOf ("=") + 1, (line.length () - "ms".length ()));
       Double ping = Double.valueOf (pingAsString);
       System.out.println ("PING AS STRING = "+ping);
   }
}
```

OK SORTED. THAT JUST NEEDED TO MOVE LINE ASSIGNMENT. CAPS. but made it clear. :D

Comment: Why not use regex? Something like that might work, time=(\d)+

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or you can just use the available methods on `String` if you do not want to perform reg-ex magic

```
String line = ...
String pingAsString = line.substring( line.lastIndexOf("=")+1, (line.length() - " ms".length() ) );
Integer ping = Integer.valueOf( pingAsString );
```

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "4.60"

@LINE : Integer ping = Integer.valueOf( pingAsString );

Comment: Of course, 4.60 is not an Integer so it cannot be parsed. Use a double instead

Comment: herpderp :D lol its been a long week... 
brilliant nearly there except...
Now it just seems to have a niggle, its missing the first value, taking 2nd, missing 3rd, taking 4th etc. so doing every other and missing first.

being new to here ill edit my main post and add on my code there, not sure if i can do it in this comment?

Answer (score 3):

Try using a [RegularExpression](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/) to pull out the piece of data you need:

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class RegExTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String test = "line= 14103 64 bytes from ziva.zarnet.ac.zw (209.88.89.132): icmp_seq=119 ttl=46 time=199 ms";

        // build the regular expression string
        String regex = ".*time=(\\d+).*";

        // compile the regular expresion into a Pattern we can use on the test string
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);

        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(test);

        // if the regular expression matches, grab the value matching the
        // expression in the first set of parentheses: "(\d+)"
        if (matcher.matches()) {
            System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner (new File ("./sample.log")); 
while (scanner.hasNext ())
{
    String line = scanner.nextLine (); 
    if (line.startsWith ("64 bytes")) {
         String ms = line.replaceAll (".*time=([0-9]+) ms", "$1");
         System.out.println ("ping = " + ms); 
    } // else System.out.println ("fail " + line); 
}
```

Your problem is, that you call:

```
if (scanner.nextLine ().startsWith ("64 bytes")){
```

which means the line is grabbed, but not assigned to a variable. The result is immediately tested for startingWith, but then you call nextLine again, and get the next line, of course:

```
   String line = scanner.nextLine ();
```

That is the second line.

Comment: the data does start with 64 bytes, i was just misleading you as i copied from the console window where i had created a counter so i knew i had all the data.

Comment: So I removed my remark, and my solution should work. Note, that I now explain how to call nextLine only once.

Comment: following your example :

String line = scanner.nextLine (); 
if (line.startsWith ("64 bytes")) {
     String ms = line.replaceAll (".*time=([0-9]+) ms", "$1");
     System.out.println("ping = "+ms);
}

was used adding the println for checking and i didnt get anywhere near my desired output, some of the strings have been appended to just ping = XX but most are still the original string. also there doesnt seem to be a noticeable pattern to it, sometimes 20 in a row are changed some times 1 in 30.

Comment: Is the time always specified in ms? Is there always a newline between 2 entries? Note: if you only want to append the time to the output, you needn't transform it to a Double. An int would be more appropriate, since there is never a fraction of ms returned, is there? Maybe you can provide an example logfile at github or somewhere, if you don't find an error.

Comment: @user1290213: I created a logfile by pinging different hosts, and my script extracts all times as expected.